# Marquee is not showing in IE 9, but its working fine in lower versions

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, marquee

I have a website in which there is a marquee section in the below part of my home page. It works fine for me in Chrome, Mozilla and all even in IE8, but it does not shows anything in IE9.

Could someone help me with the same, please?

http://www.kidzntoyz.com/index.php

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marquee not working right in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698706/marquee-not-working-right-in-firefox)

Answer (score -1):

Marquee and Blink are not standard, and are no longer supported in newer browsers. Sorry.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element
- http://themarqueeblink.com/

Comment: marquee works in firefox still, and that isn't an answer... an answer would be to recommend doing it in javascript, or similar.