# Marquee not working right in firefox

Tags: html

I am using a marquee, it's going fine in chrome, but in firefox it shows only the first div again and again. Here's the code :

```
<marquee direction="up" scrollamount="3">           
     <div class="eachnews">

    <a href="#"> <div class="news-date"><span class="day_news">15</span><span class="month_news">Apr</span>
     </div>
     <div class="news-descript"><h2>News Title</h2>
     <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.
     </p>
     </div></a>
     </div>


         <div class="eachnews">

    <a href="#"> <div class="news-date"><span class="day_news">16</span><span class="month_news">Jan</span>
     </div>
     <div class="news-descript"><h2>News Title</h2>
     <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.
     </p>
     </div></a>
     </div>



         <div class="eachnews">

    <a href="#"> <div class="news-date"><span class="day_news">17</span><span class="month_news">Oct</span>
     </div>
     <div class="news-descript"><h2>News Title</h2>
     <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.
     </p>
     </div></a>
     </div>


         <div class="eachnews">

    <a href="#"> <div class="news-date"><span class="day_news">18</span><span class="month_news">Mar</span>
     </div>
     <div class="news-descript"><h2>News Title</h2>
     <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.
     </p>
     </div></a>
     </div>

     </marquee>
```

the div where it is written "15 apr" is just repeating itself in ff, in chrome all divs are cycling fine. pls help

Comment: it worked ok in ff 23.0.1

Comment: `marquee` does not belong to the HTML standard - don't use it!

Comment: Confirming - works fine for me in FF too. Trying running FF in safe mode with all extensions turned off to verify

Comment: Start using css3 properties or javascript for marquee. Marquee tag is about to go even it has been gone.

Answer (score 2):

Marquee and Blink are not standard, and are no longer supported in many newer browsers, including versions of FF and IE. Sorry.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

However you can simulate them/reimplement them using javascript, if you really must.

- http://themarqueeblink.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `marquee` tag as it is not part of the standard and you can't assure support by the browsers (theoretically the vendors could drop the support anytime). Instead try a simple scripted solution like [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee) or by using this supersmall script I wrote:

http://jsfiddle.net/4kN5q/1/

It runs smoother in all browser that I tested (Ch,FF,IE) than the "native" marquee.