# How to make marquee of list items using css?

Tags: css, listitem, marquee

The problem is that I want to slide list items one by one and don't know how to do this. I searched over the net and get solutions that contains java script code.
Please provide appropriate solution. Thank you.

Comment: `and get solutions that contains java script code` Why don't you use that solution..?

Comment: does each list item fill the width of the container?

Comment: are you talking about an accordion menu? or a carousel? or something completely different? Please clarify your question.

Comment: As @Nick said I would rather use javascript then the marquee element in this case. Marquee is marked obsolete. IE/FF already don't support it anymore [It still amazes me ... IE removed the support of this tag. Background: Marquee was established by IE3. Then with IE 8 (quite old I know) marquee isn't supported anymore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698706/marquee-not-working-right-in-firefox / http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/marquee.shtml ]. I guess Chrome will also remove the support in one of the next versions. - So tell me, why do you still want to use it.

Comment: Hello @Nick sir, I dont want to use java script because i'm a beginner and want a simple solution by css.

Comment: @Danield sir, each item will fill the width of the container. I just want to marquee the text on the screen that comes after previous text. I hope you will understand my problem.

Comment: @jbutler483, It is neither and accordion menu nor a carousel. And even it is simple text slider that moves text from right to left. And at a time we can see only one list item. That list item will be stay on the screen for some time for example 10 seconds.